# Possible to replace HP320G5p harddrive with OEM part?

Tags: hp, sata, hp-proliant

Can any of you tell me whether it is possible to replace the HP 250GB SATA drive named GB0250EAFJF (the drive has HP branded firmware) with a standard 250 GB SATA drive from the computer parts dealer? I assume that the bracket will fit, but will the server accept the drive if the HP firmware is missing?

Warranty is not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work just fine. In fact, I typically use lower-cost Seagate or Western Digital drives for bulk storage in DL180 G6 storage servers or where I need an extra array of SATA disks in an existing enclosure. Just replace the drive in the carrier with your new disk. Will you be using the HP Smart Array RAID controller? If so, the RAID will rebuild just fine.

Here's the `hpacucli` output of an array containing a couple of Western Digital drives. Note the `WDC WD10EACS-00Z` model numbers...

```
   Array: B
      Interface Type: SATA
      Unused Space: 0 MB
      Status: OK

      physicaldrive 1E:1:10
         Port: 1E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 10
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 1000.2 GB
         Firmware Revision: 01.01B01
         Serial Number:      WD-WCASJ2216291
         Model: ATA     WDC WD10EACS-00Z
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
      physicaldrive 1E:1:11
         Port: 1E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 11
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 1000.2 GB
         Firmware Revision: 01.01B01
         Serial Number:      WD-WCASJ2217293
         Model: ATA     WDC WD10EACS-00Z
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
```

Comment: I'm in the softraid camp, so I don't have a RAID controller, which should make things even easier. 1TB in your output looks like a lot. Did you replace the drives with different size drives?

Comment: Yes, I went from 250GB disks to 1TB. If you're talking about softraid, this should still work for you.

Comment: Sounds great! Anything to observe about the drive brackets, such as special screws (Torx/Philips)?

Comment: Nevermind, the TX10 key that's clipped to server fits the drive brackets. Now upgraded from 250GB to 2TB. Thanks! :-)